# Update Spinner from other Method

Tags: android

I have a following Spinner in the OnCreate Method:

```
    spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, accounts);
        spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter); 
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

and I want add some entries to the Spinner in a other Method like this:

```
spinnerArrayAdapter.add(value.toString());
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

but the app crashes. What can I do?
Thanks!

Comment: And what is the error from the `logcat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 possibilities:

Either:

in place where you are about to add new record to adapter:
`spinnerArrayAdapter.add("Your new item");`
`spinnerArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Or:

In your onCreate when initialising adapter add `spinnerArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);`
when you want to add record to adapter later simply call `spinnerArrayAdapter.add("Your new item");`. No need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` as it has been called by `add` internally.

in both cases you don't have to re-assign adapter to spinner.

if you initialize your adapter with array, add method will raise exception, as what adapter stores internally is `(List<T>) Arrays.asList(objects)` where `objects` is the array you provided in constructor. `asList` returns the List interface wrapper implementation over the array so it does not support add opeation. In order to be able to use adapter's add method you must provide the backing data as List with supported add/remove methods - i suggest ArrayList.

so in your case init it like that:

```
spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
        new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(accounts)));
```

or longer but more efficent (e.g. you do not create 
overhead list object to be abandoned a moment later)

```
final int length = accounts.length;
ArrayList<String> backingData = new ArrayList<String>(length);
for(int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    backingData.add(i, accounts[i]);
}
spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, backingData);
```

Comment: I always get a java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. I declareted a global Variable public ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter; at the onCreate Method I do following: spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,   android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, accounts); and in the onClick Method the 2. Possibility: spinnerArrayAdapter.add("Your new item");

Comment: what is `accounts`? Array, List or ArrayList?

Comment: Oh sorry, its a String[] array. I create the array in the onCreate Method and after that I put it into the spinner. That works fine. But when I want to add another Item within the onClick Method, the app crashes.

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!! I convertet the array to a ArrayList and now it works perfekt!!

Answer (score 0):

This may works...

```
ArrayList<String> accounts = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("Item A", "Item B"));
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, accounts);

spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinnerArrayAdapter.add("Item C");
spinnerArrayAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(true);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: Thanks! The Problem is, that I dont have a xml file with Items, therefore R.layout.list_item is not known. If I try this ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,, accounts); the compiler tells me: The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined